# Display the colorbar in heatmap MATLAB

Tags: matlab, heatmap, display, colorbar

I'm creating the following heatmap:

```
h = HeatMap(CorrelationsMV, 'RowLabels', labels, 'ColumnLabels', labels, 'Colormap', map);
colorbar;
caxis([-1, 1]);
```

And for some reason, the colorbar is displayed in a second, empty heatmap :[image]
[image]

While what I need is simply that: (that I can do manually through the GUI, but I need it to be automated)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HeatMap` graphics object does not support `colorbar` method.
You can render it to a regular axes with the method `plot`, then use `colorbar` as usual:

```
h = HeatMap(CorrelationsMV, 'RowLabels', labels, 'ColumnLabels', labels, 'Colormap', map);
```

then:

```
plot(h);
colorbar;
```

or:

```
ax=h.plot;
colorbar(ax);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using colorbar the colorbar_levels will help if using older versions of matlab.
The use is simple. you can google it

```
[h_bar]=colorbar_levels(Levls,varargin)
```